# C++ Recursive Febonacci Function

Tags: c++, function, recursion, fibonacci, segment

Below is my code. I tried to print the Fibonacci recursive function [at the very end] but it gave me segment fault. What is wrong with my code? I spent like 3 hours on this and couldn't figure it out. Can someone please be kind enough to give me some help? Thanks

```
int fibonacci (int x) {


    if (x == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (x == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
    return (fibonacci(x-1) + fibonacci (x + 2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Where (aka, what line) are you getting the seg fault?

Comment: right where the fibonacci function is suppouse to print.

Answer (score 4):

Most probably you're getting the segfault because your stack grows without control, and that's because of this line:

```
    return (fibonacci(x-1) + fibonacci (x + 2));
```

calling fibonacci() with a value greater than the original causes the non-recursive case to never be reached, causing the stack to eventually overflow, or trying to do so, as the SO will detect this and terminates your process.

So, rewrite that line as this:

```
    return (fibonacci(x-1) + fibonacci (x - 2));
```

Comment: I just noticed this and then you posted the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Currently the recursion never ends because:

```
return (fibonacci(x-1) + fibonacci (x + 2));
```

should be

```
return (fibonacci(x-1) + fibonacci (x - 2));
```

The current code leads to the stack running out of memory because you keep adding function calls infinitely and at the point where the stack is out of memory you get the crash. You can see what is happening when you follow the flow of execution with a sample number:

```
fibonnaci(2) = fibonacci(1)+fibonacci(4)
             = 1 + (fibonacci(3)+fibonacci(6))
             = 1 + (((fibonacci(2)+fibonacci(5))+(fibonacci(5)+fibonacci(8)))
             = 1 + .......
```

As you can see this never actually terminates.

Comment: copy-paste error? Your correction still has x+2 (Edit - there you go)